# PHP 5.3.24 hashing options

Tags: php, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I am working on a website for a friend who is using Godaddy for their web hosting.  Currently Godaddy's most recent PHP version offered is 5.3.24.  I would really like to use bcrypt to hash user passwords for this site, but my understanding from doing some research is that you need to have at least PHP version 5.3.7 to use bcrypt.  Can anyone suggest my best/most secure options for hashing password using PHP 5.3.24? Thanks :)  I

Comment: Additionally, you can check for algorithm support using the following constants:
CRYPT_BLOWFISH, CRYPT_SHA256, CRYPT_SHA512
If they are equal to 1, then that algorithm should be available to the crypt() function

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  For some reason I was thinking in decimals and not version numbers.  Making 5.3.7 really 5.4.70.  Ha, thanks a ton.